# Linux pip, Where does it install software?

Tags: linux, pip

I can use pip freeze to see all the software installed.

**QUESTION:**

How can I use pip to find `WHERE` the software is located.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pip show <package-name>`

Example:

```
➜ pip show Django
---
Name: Django
Version: 1.6
Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires
```